# Tap and swipe gesture on same view

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have two gesture tap and swipe on same view. Whenever user tries to swipe the view, tapGesture gets recognise. I want tap to be ignored in this case. How to do that. 
Below is the code. 
This is not the case of simultaneous recogniser because swipe gesture is not getting called.

```
     UITapGestureRecognizer *gest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(itemSelected:)];
     gest.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
     [messageView addGestureRecognizer:gest];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGest = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(itemSwiped:)];
    swipeGest.direction =  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ;
    [messageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGest];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone - gesture recognizers fighting each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438374/iphone-gesture-recognizers-fighting-each-other)

Answer (score 1):

While the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438374/iphone-gesture-recognizers-fighting-each-other) is fine, a simpler solution might be to require the tap gesture to wait for the swipe gesture to fail using `- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`. This method "creates a relationship with another gesture recognizer that delays the receiver’s transition out of `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible`." In your case, the code would look like:

```
[gest requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGest];
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-requiregesturerecognizertofail?language=objc).

Comment: Hi I want to swipe gesture to be called first instead of tap. I have following code is it correct? Which condition is correct?

[tapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGesture];

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if ((gestureRecognizer == swipeGesture) && otherGestureRecognizer == tapGesture) {
        return YES;
    }
//    if (gestureRecognizer==tapGesture && otherGestureRecognizer==swipeGesture)
//        return YES;
    return NO;
 }

Answer (score 0):

In your handlers `itemSelected` and `itemSwiped`, be sure that you are checking the `state` of the `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Possible states include: `possible`, `began`, `changed`, `ended`, `cancelled`, and `failed`.

You should likely be looking for the `ended` state.

Comment: Yes I am checking the state.

Comment: I am trying to add a swipe and tap on same view and I want swipe to be called first but I always end up touch gesture being called first.